# How to insert int NULL into numeric database field?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, nullable

I am trying to insert a NULL value into a numeric database field from a winform textbox using C#. I am creating an app to enter production data into a database. Quantity variables are set as int? to accept null since there wouldn't be a value to enter if a piece of equipment sat down. The database fields also have a default value set to Null. How would I be able to leave a textbox blank and enter Null into the database field? I have scaled down my code to include what is affected.

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int? runQty = 0;
        int? scrapQty = 0;

        try
        {
            dbConn = new OleDbConnection();
            dbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ch + strDataFilePath + ch;
            dbConn.Open();

            sql = "INSERT INTO DailyProduction (runQty, scrapQty)" +
            "Values (@runQty, @scrapQty)";

            dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);

            if (runQty.HasValue)
            {
                runQty = Convert.ToInt16(this.runQuatity.Text);
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@runQty", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = runQty;
            }
            else
            {
                runQty = null;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@runQty", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = runQty;
            }

            if (scrapQty.HasValue)
            {
                scrapQty = Convert.ToInt16(this.scrapQuantity.Text);
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@scrapQty", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = scrapQty;
            }
            else
            {
                scrapQty = null;
                dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@scrapQty", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = scrapQty;
            }

            dbCmd.Connection.Close();
            dbConn.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Record Entered!");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + err.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: `runQty.HasValue` doesn't make sense, as you haven't given `runQty` a value yet. It will always be 0 at this point. It should be `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.runQuatity.Text)`. Same goes for the other IF

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/30df6f92-5f8b-483a-b534-132e78bdff48/how-to-set-oledb-parameter-to-null?forum=vblanguage says to set the value to `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Convert.ToInt16() is where your problem lies. It will convert null to 0, by design. You need to check if runQuantity.Text is empty and then set DBNull as parameter value.

Comment: the parameter is null by default if you do not add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whatever a string is null or empty using `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` methods:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
    ...
}
```

Also, for `null` values you should use `DbNull.Value`:

```
dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@runQty", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = DbNull.Value;
dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@scrapQty", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = DbNull.Value;
```

Comment: Thank you, I saw this type of solution in another post but, didn't think string would work as I am using an int. I should have tried anyway. This works exactly how I ant it to.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
var runQty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.runQuatity.Text)
    ? DBNull.Value
    : Convert.ToInt16(this.runQuatity.Text);
dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@runQty", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = runQty;

var scrapQty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.scrapQuantity.Text)
    ? DBNull.Value
    : Convert.ToInt16(this.scrapQuantity.Text);
dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@scrapQty", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = scrapQty;
```